# Unable to browse discovery service url through Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, debugging, certificate, wcfserviceclient

I have a wcf service with bindings as basicHttpBinding. I am trying to connect to client environment using clients discovery url. I had made changes in Hosts file and added this  in App.Config. This works fine if i create a installer. I am able to connect to clients discovery url and get the metadata but if i want to connect in debug mode it throws an exception"SYSTEM ERROR:Discovery Service url is not accessible."
If I directly browse the url in browser i can browse it and it ask for permission as it dont have a valid certificate.
Can anyone help me why it is not working in debug mode.

Comment: Have you tried running VS as Administrator?

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT.. yes already running under administrator.

Comment: Do you debug your app? If so, how about running it using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)"?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to your firewall or Authentication on WCF. When you debug, it will use the local machine account . The installer you are saying might be using different account .

Comment: @saravankumar v installer is using the same credential. It is running under(Local System).